# How to insert a multidimensional array

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

want to save the data of the following format

```
{"_ibj_id":"1","url_id":'1',"url":{"0":"http://0.com","1":"http:://1.com"}}
```

Look at my code,

```
type db_list struct {
    Url_id int
    Url    map[int]string
}
func list(table *mgo.Collection) {

    var doc *goquery.Document

    var e error

    for i := 1628644; i > 1628643; i-- {

        if doc, e = goquery.NewDocument("http://www.120ask.com/list/all/" + strconv.Itoa(i)); e != nil {

            panic(e.Error())

        }

        var save_list db_list

        save_list.Url_id = i

        save_list.Url = make(map[int]string)

        //fmt.Println("%s", doc.Text())

        doc.Find(".q-quename").Each(func(n int, s *goquery.Selection) {

            href, isTrue := s.Attr("href")

            if isTrue {

                save_list.Url[n] = href

                fmt.Println("%D : %s", n, save_list.Url[n])

            }

        })

        fmt.Println("%D", len(save_list.Url))

        //save database

        table.Insert(save_list)

    }

}
```

The database will eventually save
Please view the picture in the annex, is to save the format of the data, save the URLvalue of the property 1[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're probably after the [JSON Unmarshal](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) function in [`encoding/json`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/)

`{"_ibj_id":"1","url_id":'1',"url":{"0":"http://0.com","1":"http:://1.com"}}` is technically invalid JSON due to the single-quotes around the `url_id` value( `'1'` should be `"1"`) but other than that, it should map nicely to the following struct:

```
{
id string
url_id string
urls []string
}
```

But you may need to experiment with the types. According to the docs for the `Unmarshal` function, it will use the following Go types for each JSON type:

```
bool, for JSON booleans
float64, for JSON numbers
string, for JSON strings
[]interface{}, for JSON arrays
map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
nil for JSON null
```

I'd highly recommend reading [Andrew Gerrands Blog Post "JSON and Go"](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go).

Comment: I want the url of this field can store arrays

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me exactly what you are trying to do. One thing I notice though, is that in your desired format the keys for Url are string values where as in Go they are integers. You could try changing the type of `Url` to `map[string]string` and see if that solves your problem.